# BV on cyclic cohomology

Tags: homological-algebra, infinity-categories

Suppose that A is an associative algebra, but not Frobenius. Does the Cyclic Cohomology of A have a structure of a BV algebra?

All results I could find first identify A with its dual but I am asking about a general associative A.